# OCCI 19.3.0: createConnection crashes with OCCIUTF16

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-studio, occi

we would like to upgrade from occi 18 to occi 19.3.0.0.0 because we want to be independent of old MS libraries (MSVCR120.DLL).

But there is the following error while connecting the database:

```
"Program: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll

File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring

Line: 1695 Expression: string subscript out of range



For information ..."
```

When we remove "OCCIUTF16", "OCCIUTF16" in createEnvironment the connection succeeds.

We also recognized, that oci.dll was not loaded in this simple programm using occi 19. With occi 18 oci.dll was loaded.

```
#include "occi.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    try {
        // OK
        //auto env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::Mode(Environment::OBJECT | Environment::THREADED_MUTEXED));
        //auto conn = env->createConnection("SCOTT", "tiger", "ORATEST");

        // ERROR
        auto env = Environment::createEnvironment("OCCIUTF16", "OCCIUTF16",    Environment::Mode(Environment::OBJECT | Environment::THREADED_MUTEXED));
        UString user((utext*)L"SCOTT");
        UString pwd((utext*)L"tiger");
        UString host((utext*)L"ORATEST");
        auto conn = env->createConnection(user, pwd, host);
    }
    catch (SQLException & ex) {
        cout << ex.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Environment:
ORACLE SERVER 12.1.0.2
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Compiler Version 15.9.13

## Basic Light Package Information

Wed May 29 22:35:38 MDT 2019

Client Shared Library 64-bit - 19.3.0.0.0

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/occi-19-3-0-createconnection-crashes-with-occiutf16-6999

Answer (score 0):

- Can you provide the complete stack when it fails
- The issue you are pointing at MSVCP140D.dll  (D - Debug) -> so, I presume you are compiling with ORAOCCIxxD.LIB (Debug version). If you are using debug build, please use all components in debug build.
- Yes, OCI.DLL will not be loaded along with ORAOCCI.DLL now.

Thanks,
-P. Venkatraman.